# NFC Permission Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, permissions, nfc

I am working on an application that uses NFC and I keep getting this error,

```
`12-28 14:19:41.962: E/AndroidRuntime(27523): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.clinkguitest/com.example.clinkguitest.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: NFC permission required: Neither user 10168 nor current process has android.permission.NFC.`
```

I have `android:permission="android.permission.NFC"` in my manifest so what is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: From which Activity lifecycle method are you attempting to capture NFC traffic?

Comment: Did you reinstall the app after you added the NFC permission?

Comment: Yock, I am doing it on Resume. Ninetwozero, Yes I uninstall it and then use the run function in eclipse with the android SDK to install and execute it on my phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my manifest permissions look like this:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
```

Maybe that's the problem?